# Read a CVS/JSON file and navigate through it by inputting a value from a column

Tags: ruby, csv

I want to be able to print out just one row of the file by inputting a value of a specific column. I'm very new with Ruby, I'm just starting with the basics, and the guides I've found about the CSV class are not clear enough for me. Basically, I'm able to print out the whole CSV, but not just one row of it.

For example:

```
Column A,Column B
Pizza,Pie
Papa,John
```

Say I have this CSV, I want to create a code that'll search the user input (gets.chomp?) through one specific column (B, for instance). So, if I write "Pie", it should print Pizza, Pie. Or better yet, let me access the items in that specific array (that of the row) and store them as variables that I can print out in whatever order I want.

IN my lack of expertise, I've only been able to print the entire array (all rows, all columns), but surely one of you must know how to do what I'm trying, or at least make it clearer than the info I can find online.

This is the very basic code I managed to find online, but I'm not able to move past it yet.

```
CSV.foreach('file.csv') do |row|
  puts row.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't supply a block (`do |row| ... end`), `CSV.foreach` will return an Enumerator. That's useful because you can all any Enumerable method on it like `select`, `sort`, or... `find`:

```
#                                                    ↓↓↓↓
matching_row = CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true).find do |row|
  row["Column B"].include?("Pie")
end
# => #<CSV::Row "Column A":"Pizza" "Column B":"Pie">

p matching_row["Column A"] # => Pizza
```

This would be easy to turn into a method that takes (for example), column name and value arguments:

```rb
def find_row_in_csv(file_path, column_name, search_value)
  CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true).find do |row|
    row[column_name].include?(search_value)
  end
end

matching_row = find_row_in_csv("data.csv", "Column B", "Pie")
# => #<CSV::Row "Column A":"Pizza" "Column B":"Pie">
```

You can see this in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/ImmaculateGummyVoxels

Comment: Thanks for keeping it simple, it’s very clear now! P.S: the spaces before the values are not in the file, I just messed up while writing the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
matching_rows = []
input = STDIN.gets.chomp
CSV.foreach('file.csv') do |row|
  matching_rows << row if row[1].to_s.include?(input)
end

pp matching_rows
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a little bit?